# Transferring builds from one Minecraft world to another on Nintendo switch?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, nintendo-switch

I'm on Nintendo switch, there's a few builds i have scattered throughout my worlds, and I want to compile them in one world, but it would take literal years to rebuild, I don't have a computer, and nothing on YouTube works on switch, can anyone help?

Comment: Does switch have access to admin commands? If not i don't know that there is a way to do it unfortunately. With admin commands you can essentially copy paste a large cube of space which would allow you to relocate them.